# python adding multiple json commands into a json file

Tags: python, arrays, json

I've been scratching my head on how to merge two different json arrays to create one, so I can then parse that and find the commands I want.

{
"commands": {
"/command1": "hello1",
"/command2": "hello2",
"/command3": "hello2"
}
}

Would be what I am looking for however whenever I try to add the new command it looks like:

{"command1:"hello1"} underneath it not connected. I am unsure on where/how  to merge the multiple commands into one file so any info would help, thanks

Comment: So you are trying to extract a given command or the first one?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: JSON files do not contain "commands", and the result from reading a JSON file is not an "array". I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please show: 1) an example of *exactly* what is contained in input file 1; 2) an example of *exactly* what is contained in input file 2; 3) the corresponding *exact* desired output; 4) the *exact* code that you *actually tried* to solve the problem; 5) the *exact* resulting output (and explain what's wrong with that output).

Comment: {
  "commands": {
    "/command1": "hello1",
    "/command2": "hello2",
    "/command3": "hello2"
  }
}

I would like to create this but with multiple commands each time, sorry if I'm wording it wrong.